# github API - Unable to update a repository permission for a team

Tags: github-api

I am trying to update a repository permission for a team with GitHub API as

```
curl -i -u user:pass -X PUT  -d "permission:push"  https://api.github.com/teams/123/repos/j/repo
```

Getting error as

> Code: 400

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#add-team-repo"
}
```

Tried sending JSON via code. Still same error. Please help me here.

Answer (score 3):

You're not sending valid JSON. Give this a try:

```
curl -i -u user:pass -X PUT  -d '{"permission": "push"}'  https://api.github.com/teams/123/repos/j/repo
```

Comment: Posting this JSON worked for me. The GitHub docs say to add a parameter - aka `?permission=push` - but that didn't work.

Comment: does it work with organization repos as well? I