# Github API: Team permissions not updating

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

I am attempting to update a repository's team permissions through the Github API, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346907/github-api-unable-to-update-a-repository-permission-for-a-team). However, despite having receiving a 204 response, the permission does not get updated. I have full admin access over the repo and the team. I am following the documentation [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/teams/#add-or-update-team-repository).

Code snippet in Python:

```
headers = {'Authorization': f'token {token}'} 
parameters = {'permission': 'push'}
response = requests.put(f'https://api.github.com/teams/{team_id}/repos/{org}/{name}', headers=headers, params=parameters)
```

I have also tried with the key pair `'permission': 'write'` because that is one of the five permission options that appears on the repo's collaborators page, but both receive a 204 response and do not actually update the permission.

I'm doing this on a large scale for a number of repos, so I need to be able to change the permissions programmatically for each repo based on the team. I cannot tell if this is an API issue or if my code is incorrect. Thank you!

Comment: does your token have the admin:org scope ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel, yes it does.